# Powerquery / Pandas - outlook mailbox response time (table design)

Tags: pandas, powerquery

I connected to several Outlook mailboxes in powerBI. The objective is to calculate the time taken to respond to an inbound email. I've shaped the data such that the table looks like this so far:

```
Path               Topic              Sender       To           Inbound           Outbound
Inbox              Help Needed        Customer     Me           5/16/21 8:30AM    null
Inbox\Completed    New Issue          Customer2    Me           2/20/21 8:11:PM   null
Sent Items\        Help Needed        Me           Customer     null              5/16/21 9:30AM
Sent Items\        New Issue          Me          Customer2     null              5/21/21 10:30AM
```

My idea for getting the response times is to neatly transform the table so that outbound times are matched with inbound times on the same row for each `Topic` and then do add a column that subtracts `Outbound` from `Inbound`:

```
Path               Topic            Sender       To    Inbound           Outbound       Subtract
Inbox              Help Needed      Customer     Me    5/16/21 8:30AM    5/16/21 9:30AM  1:00:00
Inbox\Completed    New Issue        Customer2    Me    2/20/21 8:11:PM   5/21/21 10:30AM 2:19:00
```

Is there some sort of built-in PowerBI (or pandas) transformation that can achieve the shifting of the `Outbound` like this?

edit: one idea i have is to separate 'inbound' and 'outbound' into separate tables. Add an index to each table by grouped Topic, and then remerge them by Topic and the newly recreated ID index number

Answer (score 0):

We need to match inbound mail with outbound mail by topic. This involves separating inbound and outbound mail into 2 queries, grouping the separate queries by Topic, adding an index number to the grouped queries, and re-merging the separate queries by matching topic and newly added index number

Start by duplicating your email query, we need 1 query for Inbound and 1 query for Outbound.

For the inbound query, filter out records with `sent items` in the folder field. Do the opposite for the Outbound query

Group the query by `Topic`, aggregate by `All Rows`, name it `count`

In the grouped table, add a new column `=Table.AddIndexColumn([count],"indexNum",1,1)`.

Repeat the above steps for the `Sent Items` query. Expand both tables. Merge them on `Topic` and `indexNum`.

Ensure the tables are sorted correctly before doing any of the above, since matching is based on index number. Once you filter things in and out, powerquery might reset sorts you did previously. Wrap `Table.Buffer(` around your sorting formula to preserve sorting before grouping by.

Gonna take a rest day tomorrow